# Не работают относительные ссылки в Markdown

Tags: link, markdown

Есть сайт с документацией на генераторе Gatsby. Контент для сайта пишется в Markdown, местами содержит рабочие абсолютные ссылки на другие статьи сайта, которые хочу заменить на относительные. Прописываю их по всем правилам разметки, например:

`[link text](article-name.md)`

`[link text](../article-name.md)`

`[link text](/root/directory/article-name.md)`

При переходе по такой ссылке появляется ошибка 404 (и на локалке, и на сервере). Подскажите, что я делаю не так и в какую сторону копать?

Я новичок в этом, извините, если упускаю что-то элементарное. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: Я бы посмотрел, какие ссылки фактически получаются (можно открыть html исходник сайта в браузере через Ctrl+U). Ну и стоит указать, что за CMS или генератор сайта используется.

Comment: @insolor Генератор Gatsby. 
Исходник показал, что проблема, скорее всего, связана с другим багом, из-за которого не отображаются страницы при переходе. Так что, наверное, технически, вопрос можно считать решённым, спасибо)